# Why my DAO classes are not scanned?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've been stuck for a week with this problem and there is no way to find a solution in my project using Spring tool suite.

My dispatcher scan packages and creates beans for the controller and service layer but it seems it can't reach the model layer.

This is my `servlet-context.xml`:

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <!-- <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> -->
    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml" />
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
<!-- <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean> -->
```

I have commented the transactionManager bean because it throws an expection.

The problem comes up when in my `UserServiceImpl` set `UserDaoI` as `@Autowired`

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserServiceI{

  private static final Logger logger = 
    Logger.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);

  @Autowired
  UserDaoI userDao;

  public boolean isRegisteredUser(User user){
    logger.debug("Entrando en isRegisteredUser" + logger.getClass());
    boolean isRegistered = false;
    UserDao uDao = userDao.getUserByDni(user.getDni());
    if(!(uDao.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail()))){
        isRegistered = true;
    }
    return isRegistered;
}
```

I am clueless and desperate.

EDIT:

This is my `UserDaoI` class, but I think is not relevant.

```
public interface UserDaoI {
  void addUser(UserDao userDao);
  UserDao getUser(int id);
  boolean updateUser(UserDao userDao);
  boolean deleteUser(int id);
  List<UserDao> getAllUsers();
  UserDao getUserByDni(String dni);
}
```

This is my `UserDaoImpl.java`, the source of the problems.

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDaoI{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    Session session;

    @Override
    public void addUser(UserDao userDao) {

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(userDao);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDao getUser(int id) {
        //sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        UserDao userDao = (UserDao) session.get(UserDao.class, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateUser(UserDao userDao) {
        assert(userDao!=null);
        //sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(userDao);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteUser(int id) {
        //sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        userDao.setId(id);
        if(getUser(id)!=null){
            try{
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.delete(userDao);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                return true;

            }catch(Exception ex){
                logger.error("No se ha podido borrar el usuario");
            }finally{
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserDao> getAllUsers() {
        //sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")ArrayList<UserDao> userDaoList = (ArrayList<UserDao>) session.createQuery("from user").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return userDaoList;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDao getUserByDni(String dni) {

        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        UserDao userDao = (UserDao) session.createQuery("from user where dni = " + dni).uniqueResult();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return userDao;
        }   
}
```

Why I do not need to autowire my Session?

This is my hibernate config

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gen</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">fiw48asi</property>
   <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
   <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <mapping class="com.library.app.dao.user.UserDao"/>


</session-factory>
```

Now the exception I get is

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: user is not mapped
```

But it is declared in hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Read the error message: *No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found*. It clearly finds your DAO. That is not the problem. The problem is that it doesn't find any Spring bean of type `org.hibernate.SessionFactory`, that is required by the DAO. Have you defined such a bean?

Comment: @KrOMaG -- please show your `UserDaoI` implementation.

Comment: @JBNizet the exception is thrown only when I set UserDaoImpl as "@Repository" and then "@Autowired" wherever I use it.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't answer my question. Have you defined a bean of type SessionFactory anywhere? That's the code that you should show. If you haven't, and you want to autowire a SessionFactory into your DAO, Spring can't, since there is no SessionFactory bean defined anywhere.

Comment: @JBNizet take a look at the update please and let me know if something is wrong,

Comment: Yes, something is wrong. You have defined a Java class with a static utility method creating and returning a SessionFactory But that doesn't define a Spring bean of typoe SessionFactory. Here's the documentation explaining how to setup Hibernate in Spring. Read it carefully. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-session-factory-setup

Comment: I am quite a newcomer on Spring  fw, but I will do my best! How can I reward your answers?

Comment: and... where is it should be declared? hibernate-annotation.cf-xml or in servlet-context?

Comment: It's a Spring configuration. It must be configured in the Spring configuration file: servlet-context.xml. Don't bother with rewarding me. I have more than enough rep points already.

Comment: Sorry @JBNizet in the link provided, can you explain what is this: "product.hbm.xml"? is that a entity? I mean I do not have any userdao.hbm.xml

Comment: product.hbm.xml is a hibernate mapping file. These files are used wen the mapping of an entity is declared using XML rather than using JPA annotations. They're not really relevant anymore.

Comment: this is so tedious! I'm going worse: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/gen'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver. This was the only thing it worked, I was able to make CRUD operations before the scan DAO problem

Comment: @KrOMaG -- it looks like you have both a `User` and a `UserDao` (in addition to the `UserDaoI` and `UserDaoImpl`) -- you need to choose an interface for your in-memory entity, typically these don't have `DAO` suffix.

Comment: User represent a user in the application while userdao represents the entity and UserDaoI-UserDaoImpl are the classes to manage transactions between both the controller and the model layers. Could be a bit confusing, you are right

Comment: Ok -- @KrOMaG -- I understand. If you prefer, I can tweak my answer to mimic your model but typically the in-memory application view of the entity is the same as the object processed by your DAO mediator to avoid state loss...

Comment: @KrOMaG -- It's very difficult to guess what might be going awry. Please provide the full exception trace and the Hibernate mapping file. But if your initial problem has been solved, and you're now seeing a new problem, ask a new question instead of modifying your existing question.

Comment: I was using hibernate.cfg.xml and annotations, that is I think the problem, not sure, thanks buddy!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is:

> 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed...: Could not autowire field:

because

> No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

In your model, you will need to define a `userDaoImpl` bean with an `@Bean` annotation and a Hibernate `SessionFactory` to allow Spring to create and inject it, e.g.,: add a method to your `UserServiceImpl` class like this:

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Bean
public UserDaoI userDao() {
    return new UserDaoImpl();
}
```

But I notice some mixing of types and models, however, which I think is at the root of your issues, so I'll explain how the **service with DAO** model works generally with a simpler model.

In a "service and data access object" model, you create a persistence mediator for each entity, conventionally with a DAO suffix and the entity is typically a simple plain ordinary Java object (POJO).

For example, to represent an in-memory user, you might model the entity as follows:

**User.java**

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    // more POJO properties as need..

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(String name) {
        return this.name;
    }

    // more POJO setters and getters...
}
```

Now we need a mediator which can create, read, update, and delete these entities from our database. In a DAO pattern, that's the role of the entity's DAO:

**UserDao.java**

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


public class UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public User getUser(long id) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    //...
}
```

We add a service layer on top of the DAO layer when services either span entities or add some (likely to change) business logic to the entity. For example, supposed we have a registration table which captures registration records in various states for each user:

**UserService.java**

```
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao

    @Autowired
    private RegistrationDao registrationDao

    public boolean isRegistered(long userId) {

        // DAOs mediate access to tables
        User user = userDao.getUser(userId);
        Registration reg = registrationDao.getRegistration();

        //
        // business logic
        //
        return isUserRegistered(user, registration);
    }
}
```

With Spring 4, though, I don't hand-code my DAO layers anymore; instead I use Spring Data JPA with the Hibernate JPA provider. [Here's a very simple example of how to make this work](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/). You're already using the Hibernate ORM, so you don't "lose" much (quite the opposite, really) by using Spring Data JPA with the Hibernate JPA provider.

Comment: Your advice contradicts the error message. Why would he declare a userDaoImpl bean, since this bean is found by scanning. It just can't be autowired because its dependency, SessionFactory, can't be found. So the bean that needs to be defined is the sessionFactory.

Comment: where is it should be declared? hibernate-annotation.cf-xml or in servlet-context?

Comment: @KrOMaG -- define your UserDaoI implementation in a file called UserDaoI.java -- I'll fill in the details in my answer...and then give you a much better & simpler alternative.

Comment: @JanNielsen I have been working on this the whole weekend and still on it. My head iis gonna blow. I' kinda dumb. I have made changes, I think I'm mixing xml and annotated configuration. what you mean by defining my UserImpl? Let's update the post!